# Can you make any prime ideal ramify in some algebraic extension?

Tags: nt.number-theory

Suppose that I have a prime ideal $p$ in $\mathbb{Q}$. Then it ramifies in some extension of $\mathbb{Q}$, namely in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt p)$. This seems like it should be true for an arbitrary number field replacing $\mathbb{Q}$. Namely, suppose that I have a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ in a number field $K$. Should there be some algebraic extension $L$ of $K$ (or even better, a quadratic extension of $K$) in which $\mathfrak{p}$ ramifies? The only criterion of a prime ramifying (which involves the prime dividing the relative discriminant of the extension) involves the assumption that $\mathcal{O}_L$ is a free $\mathcal{O}_K$-module, but this isn't true even in the case of a quadratic extension (I believe Keith Conrad has an example written up in a paper), hence my difficulty. But mostly I feel that I'm missing something trivial.

Comment: Just take the square root of an element of $K$ with valuation $1$ at the prime.

Comment: Take an element $f$ of $O_K$ which generates $\mathfrak p$ in the local ring $O_{K, \mathfrak p}$ and consider the extension $L=K(\sqrt{f})$. It is quadratic and ramifies at $\mathfrak p$ (look at the ramification index). The ramification is a local phenomena and doesn't have anything to do with the freeness of $O_L$ over $O_K$. 

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. But why would one generally require the freeness when they state the ramification criterion? For example, Milne's Algebraic Number Theory (Thm 3.35) asserts this condition.

Comment: Ramification of primes is a local phenomenon. If you complete, then you will get that the integers of the bigger extension are a free module over that of the smaller one. If that bothered you. Dedekind rings with finitely many primes have trivial class number by the approx theorem (Corps Locaux, by Serre has all of it)

Comment: Also, if p ramifies in L/Q and K is linearly disjoint from L, then p ramifies also in LK/K, right? Look at Marcus book "Number Fields"! Or Lang. To construct ramified extensions of K at p is always good to keep the p-th power roots of unity in mind! If the power of p is big enough you will get plenty of ramification above p!

Comment: J, you are referring in your parenthetical remark to www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/notfree.pdf, but this issue isn't relevant. A prime in a number field ramifies in a finite extension iff it divides the discriminant ideal of the extension, and there is *no* need for an initial hypothesis that the top ring of integers is a free module over the bottom ring of integers. (However, in the *proof* of the theorem one may localize at the prime of interest and the localized ring of integers becomes a PID, so leading to a free module as a technical convenience, not a hypothesis.)

Comment: J, you are missing something trivial: see Milne's Remark 3.39(b), where he indicates how to remove the freeness assumption by using localization. 

Answer (score 1):

Why not try to "solve a harder problem", and produce Eisenstein polynomials of whatever degree you want, over any number field? These give totally ramified extensions.